# Generic JavaScript regex validating a positive number with or without commas as thousand separators and an optional fractional part

Tags: javascript, regex

I have following regex to validate numbers in input

```
var reg = /^\d+$/;
```

Now i want to allow ,(commas) and .(period) in number field as following will some one help me writing regex to allow following number format ?

```
10000000
10,000,000
10000000.00
```

Comment: should `10,000,000.00` be matched too?

Comment: and how many decimal places strictly 2 or variable number?

Comment: Will `/^\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d*)?$/` work for you?

Comment: Can't you simply just use `<input type="number">`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use

```
/^(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+|\d+)(?:\.\d+)?$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/itEQdU/2)

If you only need to allow 2 digits after the decimal separator, replace `(?:\.\d+)?` with `(?:\.\d{1,2})?`.

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*|\d+)` - 2 alternatives:

  - `\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+` - 1 to 3 digits and one or more sequences of a comma and 3 digits
  - `\d+` - 1 or more digits
- `(?:\.\d+)?` - an optional sequence of:

  - `\.` - a dot
  - `\d+` - 1 or more digits
- $

Comment: after . last digits can only be 00, can you suggest how can do that ?

Comment: If you only allow `00` as the decimal part, replace `(?:\.\d+)?` with `(?:\.00)?`

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
^((\d{1,2}(,\d{3})+)|(\d+)(\.\d{2})?)$
```

see [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/uVxGca/1)

or

```
^((\d{1,2}(,\d{3})+)|(\d+))(\.\d{2})?$
```

if you want `10,000,000.00` to get matched to.

Answer (score 0):

Using the great accepted answer by Wiktor, I found that it didn't allow only a decimal portion, so `.25` was invalid. Also, it didn't allow a decimal at the end like `12.`.

I changed it to `^(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+|\d+)?(?:\.\d*)?$` Updated [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/itEQdU/46)

To allow only a decimal portion, I added a `?` after the whole-number group: `^(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+|\d+)?` note the `?` at the end.

The ending decimal isn't a big deal, you could take it off before testing, but I changed the `\d+` at the end to `\d*`. This allows an ending decimal, but also allows the whole value to be only `.`. It might be OK for you to have only `.`, but I'll be sending it to a back-end .NET `decimal?` type which won't like it. So I'll check if it's only 1 char and a `.` and handle that, which I think is easier and more performant than taking it off the end. `if (value.length === 1 && value[0] === '.')`