# currency regex with decimal allowed with 0

Tags: javascript, regex

With reference to my previous question [currency regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41025771/javascript-currency-regex)

I want to add an condition, i want to allow decimal only if it starts with 0

example

0.25 should be allowed
1.25 not allowed

current regex is as following

```
/^(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+|\d+)(?:\.\d+)?$/
```

which matches comma trailing etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex currency validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16242449/regex-currency-validation)

Comment: Maybe `^(?!0*[1-9][,\d]*\.\d)(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+|\d+)(?:\.\d+)?$` will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will match all the currency matches from before without decimals or decimals with 0.x*

```
/^((?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+|\d+)|(?:0\.\d+))$/
```

If you only want to match 0.xx instead of an arbitrary number of decimal places use

```
/^((?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+|\d+)|(?:0\.\d{2}))$/
```

This one changes `\d+`, one or more digits, to `\d{2}`, exactly 2 digits.

Comment: regex always been pain for me. can you explain the the second regex i appreciate in advance